# Scraping with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to gather data from this page http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number but the problem is that what i need is the link for each pokemons so for the first one, "/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)" (all i need to do after that is add "bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net" in front but i don't know how to get all of these. I've seen some examples but i did not see anything that would of helped me here. Those i've seen used for loops by getting the data inside a div but these links don't seem to be part of any div other than the main big one.

So does anyone know how i could scrape this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number").get();


for( Element element : doc.select("td > span.plainlinks > a") )
{
    /* 
     * You can do further things here - for this example we 
     * only print the absolut url of each link.
     */
    System.out.println(element.absUrl("href"));
}
```

This will already give you the **absolute** URL's of each pokemon link:

```
http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)
http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ivysaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)
http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Venusaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)
http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Charmander_(Pok%C3%A9mon)
...
```

However, if you need the **relative** URL you only have to replace `element.absUrl("href")` with `element.attr("href")`.

Result:

```
/wiki/Bulbasaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)
/wiki/Ivysaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)
/wiki/Venusaur_(Pok%C3%A9mon)
/wiki/Charmander_(Pok%C3%A9mon)
...
```

For explanation of this see: [Jsoup Selector API](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax). Some good examples can found here: [Jsoup Codebook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/).